# `biblatex` and `\includestandalone` is causing unexpected indents in a `tikzpicture` nodes printed bibliography

Tags: tikz-pgf, biblatex, standalone

I am attempting to include a `biblatex` bibliography within a `standalone` file containing a `tikz` flowchart. I am encountering a strange issue with the indents when the reference numbering is >10. For instance, my main document flowchart looks like this when I compile it independently:

[image: main doc standalone]

and looks like this when it is compiled from within another document with `\includestandalone`:

[image: main doc report]

I have no idea what is causing this indent nor whether it is coming from `tikz`, `standalone`, `biblatex` or via human error. The same effect appears in my minimally reduced example, when compiling using the generic `biblatex-examples.bib` and not using `\nocite{*}` (to cite all references in the printed bibliography), the figure looks like this:

[image: mwe without nocite]

and with `\nocite{*}` to get the numbering >10:

[image: mwe with nocite]

What is causing this indent please? I thought it was something I was doing with

```
\setlength\bibitemsep{...pt}
\setlength\biblabelsep{...pt}
```

and the other length setting `biblatex` macros but my MWE doesn't include any. I am not sure how it would make a difference but I am using the custom command

```
\newcommand\ccite[1]{\cite{#1}\addtocategory{flowchart}{#1}}%
```

so I can only print the references used within the `standalone` figure, within the `standalone` figure.

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{standtest.tex}
\documentclass[border=0pt,11pt]{standalone}%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{flowchart}%
\begin{document}%
\newcommand\ccite[1]{\cite{#1}\addtocategory{flowchart}{#1}}%
\begin{tikzpicture}%
\node at (2,0) {\ccite{baez/article}, \ccite{bertram}};%
\node[align=left,text width=20cm] (refmenu) at (15,2) {\textbf{References}};%
\node[align=left,text width=20cm] (refs) at (15,1) {\printbibliography[heading=none,category=flowchart]};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
\end{document}%
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{book}%

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{flowchart}%

\begin{document}%
%\nocite{*}  % <------------------ UN-/COMMENT to see the effects on the indent
\lipsum[1-2]
\begin{figure}[t]
\includestandalone[width=\textwidth]{standtest}
\caption{Testing standalone}
\end{figure}

\newpage
\printbibliography

\end{document}%
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inheriting the rather wide labelwidth from a shorthand. You can use the option `locallabelwidth` to force biblatex to recalculate the width:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{article}%

\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp,locallabelwidth=true]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{flowchart}%
\addtocategory{flowchart}{baez/article}
\addtocategory{flowchart}{bertram}
\begin{document}%
\cite{baez/article}, \cite{bertram}, \cite{kant:kpv}
\printbibliography
\printbibliography[category=flowchart]
\end{document}%
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this worked for the indent but has now caused the hanging indent of references to be off (https://i.stack.imgur.com/by3os.png) - your answer answered the indent question of the references so I am happy to +1 and accept based on that, is this hanging indent a trivial fix or should I ask a new question on this hanging indent issue please?

Comment: did you compile more than once?

Comment: Yes, I use `arara` in my main document and it ran: `lualatex` -> `biber` -> `lualatex` -> `makeglossaries` - `lualatex` -> `lualatex`, I have set in my document certain bib macro lengths so will play with it and ask a new question if I can't fix it, thank you for the help