# Hanging indent with biblatex tikzpicture node bibliography is offset, how can it be controlled?

Tags: biblatex

Following on from a question yesterday for which a successful answer was provided ([`biblatex` and `\includestandalone` is causing unexpected indents in a `tikzpicture` nodes printed bibliography](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/696638/273733)), a minor issue was encountered where the hanging indent was "off" for the references in the `tikzpicture` as can be seen in my main document:

[image: actual report]

I have reduced the code down to a minimal example to reproduce the issue which can be seen here:

[image]

I read from the documentation and the answer provided from the linked question by Ulrike that you can set `locallabelwidth=true` locally within a `\printbibliography[...]` options which I have done for the `tikzpicture` bibliography so the indent is correct in my main bibliography for the `numeric-comp` style - how can I control the hanging indent within a `tikzpicture` node so that it doesn't change the indent of my main bibliography please? I am not sure what needs changing to make the indent set. Not using `locallabelwidth=true` doesn't appear to be an option as it broke the indention of the entire `tikzpicture` bibliography (from the linked question) but I am not sure how to set the indent properly. My references in the `tikzpicture` vary from the double and triple digits so manually setting the double digit values would probably break the triple digit indentation.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{flowchart}
\newcommand\ccite[1]{\cite{#1}\addtocategory{flowchart}{#1}}
\newcounter{num}
\newcommand{\increase}[1]{\setcounter{num}{#1}\addtocounter{num}{+98}\thenum}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\increase{#1}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (2,0) {\ccite{baez/article}, \ccite{bertram}};
\node[align=left,text width=20cm] (refmenu) at (15,2) {\textbf{References}};
\node[align=left,text width=20cm] (refs) at (15,1) {\printbibliography[heading=none,category=flowchart,locallabelwidth=true]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Test figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: There is a bug in the code for the local label width calculation. In your example the issue is avoided if we set `defernumbers=true,`, so that could be a workaround, but I'm not sure if that works in your actual document.

Comment: Tracked at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1306, because I don't know if I can find the proper solution in the next few minutes.

Comment: Thank you, I tried `defernumbers=true` but I prefer the numbering to start at 1 from the first citation, the tikzpicture is an appendix, I can live with the offset indent if needed more pedantic then anything! Thanks for opening an issue :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue here is that there were slight differences in the setup between the usual label width measuring and label width measuring for `locallabelwidth` that meant that in this setting all labels were treated as if there were 0. Obviously that does not give good results. The bug report is at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1306 and the issue was resolved in v3.20 of `biblatex`.

On an up-to-date system you should no longer have this issue.

---

## Old answer

For now you can replicate the fix by putting the bit in between `\makeatletter...\makeatother` into your preamble. But please remember to remove it once `biblatex` is updated. This is a highly internal macro and its definition may change at any time.

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}


\DeclareBibliographyCategory{flowchart}
\newcommand\ccite[1]{\cite{#1}\addtocategory{flowchart}{#1}}
\newcounter{num}
\newcommand{\increase}[1]{\setcounter{num}{#1}\addtocounter{num}{+98}\thenum}


\makeatletter
\def\blx@bbl@labelnumber{%
  % Used at endentry, when reading .bbl
  % only do this for the global sorting list otherwise we increment
  % the labelnumbers for each sortlist
  \ifdefempty\abx@field@localnumber
    {}% only if omitnumbers=true
    {\ifundef\abx@field@shorthand
      {\iftoggle{blx@defernumbers}
        % only if defernumbers=true, we have to define localnumber to
        % something to stop labelnumberwidth def complaining on first
        % post-backend run since there will be nothing in the .aux yet
        % for defernums localnumbers. On the second post-backend run,
        % it will have a value correct for generating labelnumberwidth
        % We also have to define a dummy value for labelnumber here for
        % first post-backend runs otherwise references to labelnumber
        % in cite styles like numeric-comp will die.
        {\ifundef\abx@field@localnumber
          {\numdef\abx@field@localnumber{0}%
           \blx@bbl@fielddef{labelnumber}{0}}%
          {}}
        {\csnumgdef{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}{%
            \csuse{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}+1}%
          \edef\abx@field@localnumber{%
            \csuse{blx@labelnumber@\the\c@refsection}}%
          \blx@bbl@fieldedef{labelnumber}{\abx@field@localnumber}%
          \blx@bbl@fieldedef{localnumber}{\abx@field@localnumber}}%
        \iftoggle{blx@skipbib}
          {}
          {\blx@bbl@labelnumberwidth@numeric{}}}
      {\csgappto\blx@bbl@data{\let\abx@field@labelnumber\abx@field@shorthand}%
        \iftoggle{blx@skipbib}
          {}
          {\blx@bbl@labelnumberwidth@shorthand{}}}}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[t]
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\increase{#1}}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (2,0) {\ccite{baez/article}, \ccite{bertram}};
\node[align=left,text width=20cm] (refmenu) at (15,2) {\textbf{References}};
\node[align=left,text width=20cm] (refs) at (15,1) {\printbibliography[heading=none,category=flowchart,locallabelwidth=true]};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Test figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}​
```

[image: Properly aligned bib entries.]

Answer (score 1):

I do not understand your values for the text width, e.g. 20cm, and also for the x|y coordinates. However, maybe this is what you want?

```
\documentclass[oneside]{book}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{flowchart}
\newcommand\ccite[1]{\cite{#1}\addtocategory{flowchart}{#1}}
\newcounter{num}
\newcommand{\increase}[1]{\setcounter{num}{#1}\addtocounter{num}{+98}\thenum}

\begin{document}
    \begin{figure}[t]
        \DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumber}{\increase{#1}}
        \begin{tikzpicture}
            \node at (0,-1) {\ccite{baez/article}, \ccite{bertram}};
            \node[align=left,text width=\linewidth] (refmenu) at (0,2.5) {\textbf{References}};
            \node[align=left,text width=\linewidth] (refs) at (0,1) 
            {\printbibliography[heading=none,category=flowchart,locallabelwidth=true]};
        \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{Test figure}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}​
```

[image]

Comment: +1 thank you for the answer, I picked 20cm just to be arbitrary and make the MWE, the MWE just represented the issue being produced in my main document which wasn't resolved by changing the width to `linewidth`, thank you though :)